# how to have a open and close tag for xml from oracle with the data is null

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have a xml generation query as below

```
select 
XMLElement(      "Persons" ,
              (select XMLAgg( XMLElement("Person" ,                         
                       XmlElement( "FirstName",First_name)  ,
                             XmlElement(  "SecondName",Second_name)  ,
                              XMLElement("LastName", last_name) 
).transform(xmltype('<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>')))

                          FROM np_persons  )

                  ) 
                    AS "RESULT" 
From dual
```

it is generating data successfully like below

```
<Persons>
<Person>
  <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
  <SecondName/>
  <LastName>Stephen</LastName>
</Person>
<Person>
  <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
  <SecondName>M</SecondName>
  <LastName>Stephen</LastName>
</Person>
</Persons>
```

here for the first record SecondName is null so tag came as `<SecondName/>`

I want it also as `<SecondName></SecondName>`
how can achieve the same?

Comment: There's something going wrong if you need `<a></a>` rather than `<a/>`. From a *logical* perspective, they convey the same information. You shouldn't expect tools that deal with XML correctly to distinguish between them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever client is demanding the same they r not convincing with the above :(

Comment: Then we *may* be able to alleviate your immediate problems (I can't provide a solution myself) but you should be aware that you're saving up future problems. It's a strong indication that they've written hand-crafted XML parsing code rather than using the multitude of libraries that are available. Any time tooling changes (such as through upgrades) that produces logically equivalent but not textually identical output, they're going to break. If you haven't signed a contract yet, avoid it. There's no real excuse these days for such code to exist.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever management already gone fwd with them :(

Comment: You cannot. This is the serialized output of an empty XML element moving forward. As has been said if the consumer cannot deal with this they are not accepting XML. As I have said before "attempts to generate or parse XML using techniques like string manipulation and regex will end in tears"

Comment: Ask your client to modify the **valid XML** manually with a stream based text editor like "sed" - don't do it on your side.

Comment: We get a large number of requests on StackOverflow from people trying to process invalid XML sent by someone else, or people trying to generate some subset of XML demanded by someone else. It's an enormous waste of everyone's time, which would not happen if people took standards conformance seriously. Standards are there to save money! Don't put up with other people imposing these costs on you.